EmEditor Technical Issue: reading issue with EmEditor when a code/text contain Arabic character the Select funaction not working well
I've encountered a critical selection behavior issue in EmEditor that affects productivity when working with mixed language content.
 Technical Details:
The text selection mechanism fails specifically when handling Arabic characters within English text paths. While the Arabic characters display correctly with appropriate font support, the selection functionality is compromised.
 Reproduction Steps:
Example path containing Arabic text:
""C:\Users\admin\OneDrive\المستندات\MEGA\ShareX-Data\Portable\ShareX.exe",0
 Observed Behavior:

When selecting the Arabic word "المستندات"
Selection incorrectly captures المست\ME
Double-click selection similarly malfunctions

 Current Environment:

Arabic font support: ✅
Arabic character display: ✅
Selection functionality: ❌

 Visual Documentation:
Live Example in action

Thank you for the report. EmEditor does not support right-to-left characters and scripts. We apologize for this missing support.
